# Creating a Swift application computing for the area of a rectangle

Tags: ios, swift

I am clueless of what to do next. Is the computation process right? How could I output the computation to the label?

[image]

Comment: Read the iBooks introduction to Swift. Come back when you get stuck with it. It will answer your question. Also try Ray Wenderlich.

Comment: I cannot tell you if your Swift code is correct, but I think the formula for area of a rectangle is width * height. See here: http://www.mathsisfun.com/area.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here. You're trying to assign and Int to something that expects a String. You're also trying to call an instance method of your Computation class without any instance of this class as the receiver. On top of that, you would have to have actually assigned values to the properties on said instance for this to have even worked. I believe this is what you meant to do.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonPressed: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputLength: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputWidth: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }        

    func displayComputation(sender: UIButton) {
        let computationObject = Computation()

        computationObject.inputWidth = inputWidth.text.toInt()!
        computationObject.inputLength = inputLength.text.toInt()!

        display.text = String(format: "%d", computationObject.rectanglePerimeter())
    }
}
```

Note: Your instances should have lowerCamelCase, and your classes should have UpperCamelCase.

It also appears that you've made a mistake in the formula if you want to compute area. What you were doing computes perimeter. This is what you want.

```
class Computation {
    var buttonPressed = 0
    var inputLength = 0
    var inputWidth = 0

    func rectanglePerimeter() -> Int {
        return inputWidth * 2 + inputLength * 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does Computation() come from? I get an error "Use of unresolved identifier".

Comment: @user139863 You should read my entire answer. Computation() creates a new instance of the Computation class. It's giving you an error because the capitalization is different from the code you're using because you didn't properly capitalize your class name.

Comment: Okay thanks! I got it now! @user139863

Comment: Just a quick question: What does %d mean?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of you class:

```
class Computation {
    var inputLength = 0
    var inputWidth = 0
    func rectanglePerimeter() -> Int {
        return 2*inputLength + 2*inputWidth // I think this is what you need    
    }
}

// later
var c = Computation()
var result = c.rectanglePerimeter()
```

But you should reconsider of what you are doing here - it is quite a mess (data types and their conversion, class naming and encapsulating, the computation of a rectangle itself, etc.). I think a basic book about object oriented programming would be a good starting point.